# Prove that $O(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: lie-groups

The indication is: Let $P$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix such that the norm of $p^k$ is smaller than a constant $C$ for every integer $k$, then $P=I_n$.

Comment: Does the title and the question have anything to do with each other? What is the question?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo You $P$ has $P^{-k} = 2^k I_n$ which has unbounded norms.

Comment: Sorry I realize that integer means positive and negative integers.

Answer (score 9):

Let $K$ be a compact subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Let $\beta:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be any inner product and consider the function $\bar \beta:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that $\bar \beta(x,y)=\int \beta(kx,ky)\,\mathrm dk$, where $\mathrm dk$ is the normalized Haar measure on $K$ (this makes sense because the function $k\in K\mapsto \beta(kx,ky)$ is continuous. One can easily check that $\bar\beta$ is an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ and that the action of $K$ on $\mathbb R^n$ preserves $\bar\beta$. This means that $K$ is conjugated to a subgroup of $O(n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In short: every compact subgroup preserves an inner product, so it is contained in the orthogonal group corresponding to that inner product, and all inner products have conjugated orthogonal groups.

Comment: This does not prove that $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ is maximal. Let $K \supset O(n,\mathbb{R})$ be compact. Then you proved that there exists a element $g$ such that $g \cdot K \cdot g^{-1} \subset O(n,\mathbb{R})$. Hence we have $g \cdot O(n,\mathbb{R}) \cdot g^{-1} \subset g \cdot K \cdot g^{-1} \subset O(n,\mathbb{R})$. To conclude you have to prove that the inclusion $g \cdot O(n,\mathbb{R}) \cdot g^{-1} \subset O(n,\mathbb{R})$ must be an equality.

Comment: @AugusteHoangDuc, well… I quite clearly stated that what I proved is that every compact subgroup is conjugated to a subgroup of $O(n,R)$. What is left is more or less trivial for all sort of reasons, and I left it for the industrious reader: for example, in that situation $gOg^{-1}$ is a Lie subgroup of $O$ of the same dimension and the same finite number of connected components.

Answer (score 6):

Let $P$ be symmetric positive. Then there is an orthogonal $Q \in O(n)$, such that $Q^tPQ = \Lambda$ is diagonal. We have $Q^tP^kQ = \Lambda^k$ for every $k\in\mathbb Z$, hence $(\Lambda^k)$ has also bounded norm, by $C'$, say. But now, for every diagonal entry $\lambda$ of $\Lambda$ with unit eigenvector $e$:
\[
  \lambda^k = \|{\Lambda^ke}\| \le C'\|e\|, \quad k \in \mathbb Z
\]
As $\lambda$ is real and positive, this implies $\lambda = 1$. So $\Lambda = I_n$ and hence $P = I_n$.

Regarding the question in the title: Let $A \in GL(n,\mathbb R) \setminus O(n)$, then there is some $x$ with $\| x \| = 1$ and $\|Ax\| \ne 1$. Let $Q \in O(n)$ with $Qx = \frac{Ax}{\|{Ax}\|}$. Then $Q^tA$ maps $x$ to $\|Ax\|x$, hence $Q^tA$ has $\|Ax\|$ as an eigenvalue. Since $\|Ax\| \ne 1$, arguing as above, no compact subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ can contain $Q^tA$. So no compact subgroup containig $O(n)$ can contain $A$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another answer using the theorem of polar decomposition, but in fact it uses the same idea to yours: Let H be a compact subgroup of GL(n,R) containing O(n).
For g belongs to H, write g=kp where `k\in O(n)` and p is symmetric positive definite. Then p=k^(-1)g which belongs to H. Hence p^k belongs to H for every interger k. Since H is compact, by the lemma we had before, p=I_n.