# Is there such a group?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a compact matrix group $G\subseteq GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $|G|$ is countable infinite?

Comment: What topology are we using? Would $$\left<\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\right>$$
satisfy your conditions? It would form a closed set in the product topology of $\mathbb{R^{n^2}}.$

Comment: @Melody But it is not bounded.

Comment: @Paul Frost True. Nevermind.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If $G$ exists, then it must be contained in the orthogonal group $O(n)$. To see this, consider the continuous function $\det : M(n,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $G$ is compact, $\det(G)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not contain $0$. Assume there exists $A \in G$ such that $A \notin O(n)$. Then $d = \lvert \det(A) \rvert \ne 1$. Note that $A^n \in G$ and $\lvert \det(A^n) \rvert = d^n$. This shows that if $d > 1$, then $\det(G)$ is not bounded, and if 
$d < 1$, then $\det(G)$ is not closed.

Comment: There is no countable infinite compact Hausdorff group. See this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality

Comment: @Servaes $d^n \to 0$ and $0 \notin \det(G)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost There is a problem with your argument : there exists matrices $A$ such that $\det(A)=1$ and $A\not\in O(n)$. In fact $\ker\det = \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Servaes Of course. But we know that $\det(G)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so it must contain $\lim d^n = 0$.

Comment: @Roland You are right. So my argument only shows that $G$ must be contained in the set of matrices with $\det(A) = \pm1$.

Comment: @freakish You should give an official answer, even it is essentially a reference.

Answer (score 4):

So the answer is negative. In general there is no countably infinite and compact Hausdorff group. See this:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939/is-there-a-compact-group-of-countably-infinite-cardinality

To add a bit to the answer (so that it isn't completely naked ;) ): every compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is obviously contained in the preimage $\det^{-1}(\{-1,1\})$ which is the largest compact subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$. But we can do better. The orthogonal group $O(n)$ is a maximal subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ among compact subgroups (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202850/prove-that-on-is-a-maximal-compact-subgroup-of-gln-mathbb-r)). Therefore every compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subconjugate of $O(n)$ which is a consequence of the Cartan-Iwasawa-Malcev theorem.

In particular if you wish to analyze compact subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ then it is enough to look at subgroups of $O(n)$.