# Maximal Proper Subschemes of $\operatorname{GL}_n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, schemes, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, and fix some dimension $n$. It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202850/869257) that the orthogonal group $\operatorname O_n(k)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$, in the sense that any compact subgroup $H\subseteq\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is conjugate to some subgroup of $\operatorname O_n(K)$. There is a $p$-adic analogue, for which I refer to [Conrad's exposition](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/maxcompact.pdf).

I am interested in an analogue in algebraic geometry, for a general field $k$. More concretely, is the following statement true?

> Fix a field $k$. Then there is a maximal proper algebraic subgroup $H$ of the algebraic group $\operatorname{GL}_n$ in the following sense: for any proper algebraic subgroup $H'\subseteq\operatorname{GL}_n$, we can conjugate $H'$ into an algebraic subgroup of $H$.

If this is not true, can one add suitable adjectives (for example, to $k$ or to the subscheme) to make it true?

Comment: Up to conjugation it contains $\mathrm{SL}_n$ and because of this one can quickly reduce to the case of $\mathbb{G}_m$. But there the answer is obviously no: the algebraic subgroups are just the $\mu_N$ for $N\geqslant 1$ and these have no largest member.

Comment: $O_n(\mathbb C)$ is not compact.